# Is java 8 supplier replacing constructor call

Tags: java

I've been looking at the Supplier and Consumer interfaces of Java 8 and of what I understand it can replace constructor call.
I've seen an example on dzone ([link here](https://dzone.com/articles/factory-pattern-using-lambda-expression-in-java-8)) where a ShapeFactory is used.
The code is pretty simple, a simple factory for a shape class.
But she uses it as so :

```
Supplier<ShapeFactory> supplier = ShapeFactory::new;
supplier.get().getShape("rectangle").draw();
```

But why is it better than doing a simple classical :

```
ShapeFactory factory = new ShapeFactory();
factory.getShape("rectangle").draw()
```

This being much simpler and efficient enough. Besides, if the constructor of the ShapeFactory class has argument, Supplier will not work and we will have to use Function or other methods.

So why use the Supplier like this in this precise case ?

Comment: `ShapeFactory::new;` <-- this is pretty much constructor call

Comment: He's actually calling `new ShapeFactory()` twice (through the `Supplier.get()` calls).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the example above, it makes no sense to complicate things with the supplier. 
A simple constructor call is even easier to read (and is likely to be faster). 
*Probably,* the author of this examle intended to demonstrate how a `Supplier` can be invoked.

Suppliers become useful when you need to **extract the retrieval (which is not necessarily creation) of an object,** kind of "strategy pattern". 
E.g.:

```
public void drawRectangle(final Supplier<ShapeFactory> factorySupplier) {
    final ShapeFactory factory = factorySupplier.get();
    factory.getShape("rectangle").draw();
}
```

Then, you could call your method like this, and it would create a new factory:

```
drawRectangle(ShapeFactory::new);
```

or for example like this:

```
@Autowired
private ShapeFactory shapeFactoryBean;
...
drawRectangle(() -> shapeFactoryBean);
```

and it would use an existing factory instead of creating a new one.

---

Of course, the method from my example could just take a `ShapeFactory` as an argument. But one could imagine a situation that, for example, the factory only needs to be accessed in certain situations, so there's no need to create a new factory for the method call, e.g.:

```
public void drawRectangleConditionally(final Supplier<ShapeFactory> factorySupplier) {
    if (something) {
        final ShapeFactory factory = factorySupplier.get();
        factory.getShape("rectangle").draw();
    }
}
...
drawRectangleConditionally(ShapeFactory::new); 
// the factory will only be created if it's really needed.
```

---

Note that **a supplier can be used multiple times,** so another use of suppliers is to get a sequence of objects, e.g.:

```
public List<T> createList(final int n, final Supplier<T> listItemSupplier) {
    final List<T> result = new ArrayList<>(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        result.add(listItemSupplier.get());
    }
    return result;
}
...
createList(5, MyObject::new); // creates a list of 5 MyObjects
createList(3, () -> "hello"); // creates a list of 3 "hello" strings
createList(10, Random::nextLong); // creates a list of 10 random longs
```

Answer (score 9):

**TLDR**

Using a `Supplier` brings **better readability/maintainability** than explicit constructor invocation such as the `new MyObject()` idiom handled by `switch`/`if-else if` statements.
It also brings a **better type safety** that instantiation by reflection, an alternative to  the `new MyObject()` idiom, often used before Java 8 to address the maintainability concern but that introduces other issues.

---

Instantiating a `Factory` class is not necessarily the best example to illustrate benefits of `Supplier`.
So, suppose we want to instantiate `Shape` classes from a `Factory` class.

A factory of `Shape` should instantiate different kind of `Shape` (subclasses of it).

1) Without `Supplier` and with a `new MyShape()` idiom, you will finish with a method that contains some `if-else if`/`switch` statements that checks a kind of criteria/parameter and instanties the expected class according to this criteria/parameter.
For example :

```
public static Shape createShape(String criteria) {
    if (criteria.equals("circle")){
        return new Circle();
    }
    else if (criteria.equals("square")){
        return new Square();
    }
    ...
}
```

It is bad because when you add a class to handle by the method, you have to change this method with a new `if-else if`/`switch` so that it takes it in consideration.
It results to a not maintainable code where you may fast create side effects.

2) To avoid this problem, we use often reflection with `Class.newInstance()`.
It eliminate the `if-else if`/`switch` problem but it creates often others as reflection may not work (security issue, class not instantiable, etc...) and you will know it only at runtime.
It results still to a brittle code.

**Here are the reasons to favor the `Supplier` :**

By providing a `Supplier`, **the check is performed at compile time**  : if the class is not instantiable, the compiler will emit an error.
Besides, the method that uses/accepts a `Supplier<Shape>` doesn't need to use   `if-else if`/`switch` statements.

When you use `Supplier`, you encounter generally two cases (not mutually exclusive of course) :

- the `Supplier<Shape>` objects are instantiated by the factory class.
  We can so for example use in the factory a `Map` that stores the `Supplier<Shape>` instances and 
  **modifying the code to add/remove elements in the map is really cleaner as adding a new branch to a `if-else if`/`switch` statement** as it is much less verbose and the way to change the map populating (add a `map.put()` or remove `map.put()` statement) is less prone to create side effects.
- the `Supplier<Shape>` objects are instantiated and provided by the client class.
  In this case, the factory doesn't even need to change.
  **So the map is so even not required**.
  **And from the client side, while the client provides a valid  `Supplier<Shape>` parameter, it is fine**.

Type safety, maintainable code : as you may notice, these two ways using the `Supplier<Shape>` address completely drawbacks of `new MyShape()` and instantiation by reflection idiom.

---

I will give two examples to illustrate these two ways.

---

Example where the `Shape Supplier`s are created in the factory :

```
public class SimpleShapeFactory {


    private static Map<String, Supplier<Shape>> shapesByCriteria = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        shapesByCriteria.put("square", Square::new);
        shapesByCriteria.put("circle", Circle::new);
    }

    public static Shape createShape(String criteria) {
        return shapesByCriteria.get(criteria).get();
    }           

}
```

The client may invoke it in this way :

```
Shape square = SimpleShapeFactory.createShape("square");
Shape circle = SimpleShapeFactory.createShape("circle");
```

This code will not fail at runtime because of the instantiation of `Square` or `Circle` as it is checked at compile time.
And the task for instantiating `Shape` instances are at a same place and easy to change :

```
static {
    shapesByCriteria.put("square", Square::new);
    shapesByCriteria.put("circle", Circle::new);
}
```

---

Example where the `Shape Supplier`s are provided by the client:

```
public class ComplexShapeFactory {

    public static Shape composeComplexShape(List<Supplier<Shape>> suppliers) {
        Shape shape = suppliers.get(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < suppliers.size() - 1; i++) {
            shape = shape.compose(suppliers.get(i + 1).get());
        }

        return shape;
    }    

}
```

The client may create complex shapes by chaining `Supplier` in this way as it invokes the method:

```
Shape squareWithTwoCircles = ComplexShapeFactory.composeComplexShape(Arrays.asList(Square::new, Circle::new, Circle::new));
```

The check is still done at compile time and as the supplier is provided by the client, the client can add new class of `Shape` without making the factory change.

Comment: I honestly think that your answer (and the one by Alex) are  simply better than the other one that receives two upvotes already. But no idea how I managed that ... but I ran out of votes. Drop me a comment tomorrow so I can fix that. Maybe you could add more code examples, your points are a bit hard to just "think up". Reading code would be easier.

Comment: @GhostCat I agree with you, plus this answer is the only one showing the **uses** of the Supplier. Other answers don't really answer the question.

Comment: Yes but what you're saying is joining the answer @dainu gave me. The supplier for the Shape would avoid if else checks and is better than reflection.
But the supplier for ShapeFactory is quite useless in this case.

Comment: Horrible. You realize you just made half 100 k. Like starting from scratch again. But knowing much better how much work is in front of you. No, seriously, I didn't see much of a difference for me. Besides, how is your legendary counter doing?

Comment: I joked of course :) You summarized  the things very well. The legendary counter is bad. I often stop SO before reaching the 200 daily cap.

Answer (score 4):

A lot of times, a person puts in a lot of effort to learn the new technology.  Then they become heavily invested in the new technology, and start to use it preferentially over any other approach.

There's a variant of an old saying "When you have a hammer ever job looks like a nail".

I've seen Streams used when a simple for loop would have been easier to read and maintain, due to an attempt to embed flitering and switch-like logic in the stream.  I've seen for loops that were simple enough that they read better as streams.

In my estimation, this person learned Streams really well, well enough to blend the construction paradigm into their Streams in a stream-like manner.  I don't think it was a wise choice, but I would guess that if you asked them about it, their response might be "go learn streams".

Comment: +1 - I think most developers go through something like this. I remember when I first learned what a ternary expression was, I basically stopped using if/else altogether for a few weeks. "It's so terse!" - never mind the fact I couldn't read any of it the next day...

Comment: I would honestly consider to downvote this "answer" ... but lucky you, I already spent all my votes today. Seriously: I agree that people go overboard and use streams in pretty bad ways sometimes. But your answer is more of a "stretched" comment containing nothing else but "ranting". There is *nothing* in here that could be called a real fact-based argument.

Comment: Yeah I thought it was something like so. I've looked at the stream API as well and I tend to overuse them when it's not necessary and less maintainable I confess. But I did that only to learn them well, in this case a simple constructor is simpler !

Comment: For those who have chimed in, just to make sure you know.... I'm not exempt from doing this myself.  But I've done it enough times to recognize that there is a pattern to learning something new, and part of that pattern is an attempt to use it everywhere.  Over time, you start to get pushback, and settle into a happy middle ground.

Answer (score 1):

I don't find this to be a very good example of the factory pattern.
I would suggest something like

```
// "old code"
interface ShapeFactory {
    Shape create();
}

class CircleFactory implements ShapeFactory {
    Shape create() { return new Circle(); }
}

class CircleFactory implements ShapeFactory {
    Shape create() { return new Circle(); }
}

class ShapeDrawer {
    ShapeFactory factory;

    public void setFactory(ShapeFactory f) { factory = f; }

    public void draw() {
        factory.create().draw();
    }
}

// called with
shapeDrawer.setFactory(new CircleFactory());
shapeDrawer.draw();
shapeDrawer.setFactory(new RectangleFactory());
shapeDrawer.draw();

// with Supplier
class ShapeDrawer {
    Supplier<Shape> factory;

    public void setFactory(Supplier<Shape> f) { factory = f; }

    public void draw() {
        factory.get().draw();
    }
}

// called like this
shapeFactory.setFactory(Circle::new);
shapeDrawer.draw();
shapeFactory.setFactory(Rectangle::new);
shapeDrawer.draw();
```

So, there's a lot less boilerplate code around the use of the factory pattern.

Comment: Yes the supplier would be better for Shape rather than ShapeFactory, but my question was not about the factory pattern, but just to see if it was better to use the supplier for a simple instance of ShapeFactory.